# Problem to send cropped image into my server with javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new with cropping images, and i had some problems to save the cropped image. My code already upload a new image, and shows the preview cropped image, but i'm stuck on this step.

I have a code that i already tried, that sends an image to server when the image is from input div, and the element is a object htmlinputelement. When i try to send my preview picture, it is an object object and doesn't work. I saw that i have to turn my object into a file, but i don't know if this is the right way to do it, and my javascript skills aren't so good.

//this code is to send to server and it's working
function uploadpicture(input) {

```
if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
        $('#img_final')
        .attr('src', e.target.result);
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

    //enviar img via ajax
    var file_data = input.files[0];

    var form_data = new FormData();

    var cpf_can = '<%= @candidato.cpf %>';
    console.log('cpf: ', cpf_can);

    form_data.append("file", file_data);
    form_data.append("cpf", cpf_can);


    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('POST', '/changecurimg/envia3por4ajax', /* async = */ false);
    request.send(form_data);

    if (request.response == 500){
        alert("Erro ao inserir foto! tente novamente");
        location.reload();
        $("#myModal").modal('hide');
    }
    else if (request.response == 200){
        location.reload();
        $("#myModal").modal('hide');
        $('#img_final').removeClass('hidden');
        $('#img_prev').addClass( "hidden" );
    }
}
```

}

// this code shows the cropping and preview image
function resize_modal(){

```
var $image = $(".img-container > img"),
    $dataX = $("#dataX"),
    $dataY = $("#dataY"),
    $dataHeight = $("#dataHeight"),
    $dataWidth = $("#dataWidth");

$image.cropper({
  aspectRatio: 3 / 4,
  data: {
    x: 480,
    y: 60,
    width: 640,
    height: 360
  },
  modal: true,
  preview: ".img-preview",
  done: function(data) {
    $dataX.val(Math.round(data.x));
    $dataY.val(Math.round(data.y));
    $dataHeight.val(Math.round(data.height));
    $dataWidth.val(Math.round(data.width));
  }
});

var $inputImage = $("#inputImage");
if (window.FileReader) {
    $inputImage.change(function () {
        var fileReader = new FileReader(),
                files = this.files,
                file;

        if (!files.length) {
            return;
        }

        file = files[0];

        if (/^image\/\w+$/.test(file.type)) {
            fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
            fileReader.onload = function () {
                $inputImage.val("");
                $image.cropper("reset", true).cropper("replace", this.result);
            };
        } else {
            showMessage("Please choose an image file.");
        }
    });
} else {
    $inputImage.addClass("hide");
};

// $('document').ready(function(){
//     $('#myModal0').modal('show');
// };
```

};